# Zero-knowledge proof of HMAC digest

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, hmac

I'm reading the Wikipedia for [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), and I feel a little bit lost.

I'm wondering if there exists...

$$digest = \operatorname{HMAC}(msg, key)$$

Is it possible to prove that $digest$ is computed from $msg$, **without** knowing the $key$?

Answer (score 1):

No.

According to [RFC2104](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2104), the HMAC function is defined as follows:

```
HMAC(K, text) = H(K XOR opad, H(K XOR ipad, text))
```

As you can see, the HMAC function consists of two nested hash functions, where the input to each hash function includes (in part) a function of the key (K).

Therefore, `proving that the HMAC digest is computed from msg, without knowing the key` is akin to proving that a given hash is computed from an input string, given only part of the input string.  In short, this would require reversing (or brute-forcing) the hash, to find the unknown part of the string - such that, when combined with the known part of the sting, produces the given hash.  This type of reversing is exactly what hash functions are designed to be resilient to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I assume you mean "Is it possible to convince someone that the digest was computed using a publicly known message, while keeping the key secret?"

There exist [zero knowledge proof systems](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/gmw1.html) for all of NP. We can view this particular problem as the following NP Relation:

$$R_{\text{HMAC}}=\{(\text{digest}, \text{msg}; \text{key}): \text{HMAC}(\text{msg}, \text{key})=\text{digest}\}$$

where the NP witness is the key.

Thus, a ZK proof would not reveal the underlying witness (the key), but convince the verifier that the digest can be computed from the message. If the proof is also a `Proof of Knowledge`, then the verifier can also be convinced that the prover "knows" the appropriate key.

Answer (score 0):

SNARKs could be useful to produce a proof. Groth16 proof system is quite useful for producing satisfiability proofs for statements that involve hash functions.